# ResignFirstResponder crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I`m trying to down keyboard before do a NSURLResquest and loading show...

```
[self.txtComentario resignFirstResponder];
```

crashes de app...I have already tried to resignFirstResponder inside loadingThread() too

```
-(void) loadingThread {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [self.myLoadingView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
    [self.myLoadingImagem setFrame:CGRectMake(133, 250, 54, 9)];
    [appDelegate.window addSubview:self.myLoadingView];
    [appDelegate.window addSubview:self.myLoadingImagem];
    [self.myLoadingView setHidden:NO];
    [self animar];
}


-(IBAction)btnComentarClick:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[self.txtComentario resignFirstResponder];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadingThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil];


    NSString* comentarios = [kBaseURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:kComentarios];

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:comentarios]; //1

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST"; //2

    //        NSDictionary *usuarioDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:txtEmailCadastro.text, @"email", txtSenhaCadastro.text, @"senha", categorias, @"categorias", nil];


    NSMutableDictionary* jsonable = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    safeSet(jsonable, @"idUsuario", appDelegate.usuarioLogado.identificador);
    safeSet(jsonable, @"nomeUsuario", appDelegate.usuarioLogado.nome);
    safeSet(jsonable, @"textoComentario", self.txtComentario.text);
    safeSet(jsonable, @"idOcorrencia", _location._id);


    NSData* data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonable options:0 error:NULL]; //3

    request.HTTPBody = data;
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; //4

    NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

    NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) { //5
        if (!error) {
//            NSArray* responseArray = @[[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL]];
            NSLog(@"comentado");
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                    self.txtComentario.text = @"";
                [self.txtComentario resignFirstResponder];
            });
        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
    [self listarComentarios];
}
```

EDIT: if I try to resignFirstesponder before NSThread, nothing happens, no crash but not keyboard Down..If i try inside loadingThread...the app crashes

the error inside NSThread is:

> [UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called
>   from the main thread.'

Comment: You shouldn't make UI changes on secondary threads

Comment: @Leonardo and how I solve this?

Comment: All the method calls you are using in loadingThread are UI changes, you need to change where you are making these calls

Comment: But if I call txtComentario resignFirstResponder before loadingThread, it doesn't work

Comment: Try replacing [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadingThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil]; for [self loadingThread];

Answer (score 1):

It happens sometimes that asynchronous API requests won't call back to the delegate on the main thread. So, just try to ensure that you are on Main thread. If you aren't on it then try to switch to the main thread before you make any update to the UI.

```
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    NSLog(@"Yes, it is!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"No, it's not. Please switch to main");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but help me: I know that I can only update the UI in main thread, but I`m trying to do this before switch to secundary thread like is in my code shown above, but it doesn't work. Could you help me to resign the keyboard before the request and before the loading thread? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to replace with this code

```
[self.view endEditing: YES];
```

Comment: same error: [UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'

Comment: This is an attempt to answer.  Despite being terse, unsure of itself, and unhelpful to the OP, it should not be deleted via low quality posts.  (But feel free to downvote.)